# python Virtual Environments Error: 'list' object has no attribute 'read'

Tags: python, virtualenv, pyvenv

I'm following this tutorial for create a venv in python (for a flask's project on windows):
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html

When i execute the following command:

`python3 -m venv tutorial-env`

the following error is generated:

`Error: 'list' object has no attribute 'read'`

I don't understand what the cause is, can you help me?

Comment: Please provide any code example :) And specify in which folder you are relative to venv and command to launch your code

Comment: I believe its because of the hypen in the name of the environment you want to create. Try replacing it with an underscore. `python3 -m venv tutorial_env`

Answer (score 1):

I believe, it because of '-' in your virtual environment name. Try below command and make sure your python3 paths matches into command. Checkout this helpful documentation [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html).

```
c:\>c:\Python35\python -m venv c:\path\to\myenv
```

Answer (score 1):

I uninstalled a package called "subprocess.run" with "pip uninstall [package-name]" and that's all. You can run your project

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

These are the steps I follow to create a new project and use venv:
Create a folder with the project name
Open Visual Studio Code (or your IDE) and open this folder
Make sure the terminal is open, if not open it
Create a folder for the virtual environment (the folder will be called also venv but can have another name:
python -m venv venv (it can take a while until it finishes)
Activate the virtual environment:   cd venv (to enter the virtual environment folder)   ./scripts/activate (to activate the virtual environment) and
cd .. to go back to the project folder

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I tried your method but it keeps returning the same error (Error: 'list' object has no attribute 'read')

Comment: @Daniel You dont need to `cd venv` and then change the directory back. You can simply do `./venv/scripts/activate` and it will activate the virtual environment from the same directory you were in.